# unable to produce multiple rows in HTML td

Tags: html, xslt, html-table, xalan

i tried to print `td` data on multiple rows, i'm using XSLT, basically if we do the following simple example:

```
<td rowspan="3">
  X
  Y
  z
</td>
```

the output will be as follows:

```
X Y Z
```

although i put the `rowspan` attribute the content still appears on one row !!

the real code is as follows:

```
<td width="800px" rowspan="3">
 <xsl:variable name='newline'><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="recip">
        <xsl:for-each select="page/message/recipients/recipient">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() mod 5 = 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(first-name,' ',middle-name,' ',last-name,$newline)"/>
               </xsl:when>
                 <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(first-name,' ',middle-name,' ',last-name,',')"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="recipID">
<td/>
```

as i said although i print a new line using `&#xa;` the data remain appears on one line, any idea about fixing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the purpose of the `rowspan` attribute. This:

```
<td rowspan="3">
```

does *not* mean that the content of the element on which it is specified (td) is divided into three table cells. Rather, spanning multiple rows actually means that **fewer** cells are generated. In the above case, the resulting cell is as high as three "normal cells".

To illustrate this:

```
--------------------------------------------
| normal cell | normal cell |              |
-----------------------------              |
| normal cell | normal cell | cell with    |
----------------------------- rowspan="3"  |
| normal cell | normal cell |              |
--------------------------------------------
```

Now, in your stylesheet snippet, only one `td` element is being generated and it contains all the content that is output from within `<td width="800px" rowspan="3">`.

To output several table cells, write something along the lines of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="page/message/recipients/recipient">    
  <td><xsl:value-of select="first-name"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="middle-name"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="last-name"/></td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note that `td` elements must be nested inside a HTML table to be displayed correctly. (You did not show that part of your XSLT stylesheet).

---

UPDATE: If you understood all this, and really want to output three lines within one cell, this is how you can do it:

```
<td rowspan="3">X<br />Y</br />Z<br /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will always type from left to right in `<TD>`.
If you actually do want linebreaks, use `<br />` like you would everywher else.

For `rowspan`, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td. I don't think it does what you think it does.